# Possible to use Command+Tab to bring up only top Window?

Tags: application-switcher

If you switch to an open application in Alfred, it only brings up only the window on top of the windows stack for that application, i.e. only the most recently focused window of that application. Is it possible to replicate this behavior using command+tab?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any hidden preferences for it by using [strings or gdb](https://superuser.com/questions/455755/how-to-explore-more-defaults-write-tweaks-on-os-x).

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) only raises the selected window. It also displays the titles of windows and sorts windows by the order they were focused in.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I spent a bit too much time on that already and I couldn't find anything - though it is hard to belief that I am the first one to voice this request.